# Which files and directories should I ignore when putting my Yii project under version control?

Tags: php, yii, version-control, mercurial, hgignore

Using the [Yii PHP framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) with [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) as version control.

Which files and directories should I ignore when putting my Yii webapp project under version control (i.e. what to put in .hgignore)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One of the examples](http://www.tipstank.com/2010/06/10/adding-yii-php-framework-project-into-git-repository/) (for Git, but you can adapt it to Mercurial) recommends to ignore:

- `swp` – VIM swap files
- `.buildpath`, `.project`, `.settings` – files and folders generated by Eclipse
- `.idea` – folder generated by JetBrains PhpStorm
- `assets/*` – everything under assets are generated by Yii during runtime
- `runtime/*` – same goes to everything under runtime, we wouldn’t want to version control them
- `protected/data/*.db` – for sqlite users, stop version control sqlite databases
- `protected/tests/report/*` – code coverage test report (Just started practising TDD, hence this)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [default for Yii from github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Yii.gitignore), its not for mercurial but you can port it. also there are for other frameworks and IDE's

Answer (score 1):

Synthesis and generalization of the previous answers (without exact file-lists, but common principles)

For any Tool and any SCM widely-accepted rule is "Don't store working artifacts in repo, store minimal set of objects, which allow you to continue your work on any new place"

Comment: Good generic advice indeed. +1